# Python read html addresses from a file and post all results

Tags: python

```
target = open("addresses.txt", 'r+')
    for line in target:
    number = requests.get(line)
    print (number)
```

this is clearly wrong but I'm stuck it should extract the addresses from `.txt` check on the net via api and print the result

So that it should read the content of each address i.e

```
0
0
```

my addresses.txt contain

```
http://chainz.cryptoid.info/cure/api.dws?Key=3972cc3ec73f&q=getbalance&a=BPzWE91tLTGRAqTByE4AvbX79vgYGGc9ye
http://chainz.cryptoid.info/cure/api.dws?Key=3972cc3ec73f&q=getbalance&a=BPzWE91tLTGRAqTByE4AvbX79vgYGGc9pt
```

Comment: The result of `requests.get(line)` is a `Response` object, not `0`.

Comment: When I use `requests.get()` against those URLs, the `r.text` is `0`.

Comment: Yes, `r.text`, but not `r`. The question is unclear. (And of course I will not `GET` any wild URL posted in a SO question by a 1 rep member.)

Comment: All OP wants is to print out the textual results of a list of HTTP requests. Also there's nothing malicious an HTTP GET request can do to your computer via python... it's just textual, non-executable data.

Comment: Not to my computer, true. But imagine the Site hosts CP. This would result in my IP being listed in their log files. I would prefer not to.

Comment: sorry if it is unclear but when I open the url I get a number in this case it is 0 but it could be 340

Comment: for now I'm getting a error message File "C:\Users\john1\Desktop\Curecoin\Curecoin2.py", line 20, in <module>
    response = requests.get(address)
    "Perhaps you meant http://{0}?".format(url))
requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL '\n': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http://

Comment: My answer should run if you copy and paste it into a file in the same directory as `addresses.txt`. I know because I tested it. If it doesn't work, it means you don't have `requests` installed correctly.

Comment: ok the code work with -> print(response.text)

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
with open("addresses.txt") as addresses:
    for address in addresses.readlines():
        response = requests.get(address)
        print(response)
```

Comment: How is this any different from OP's attempt?

Comment: @RPGillespie The OPs attemp will not run because of broken indention.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
import requests

with open("addresses.txt", 'r') as target:
    for line in target:
        r = requests.get(line)
        print(r.text)
```

Comment: How is this different from my answer?

Comment: @LutzHorn I'm printing the response text, which is what OP wants. You are printing a response object, which doesn't convey anything meaningful.